# Считать строки из cmd в переменные

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd

Делаю небольшую оболочку на C# для программы, работающей из командной строки. Оболочка - Windows Forms. В чем проблема: из оболочки передается переменная,  основная программа на это реагирует выводом нескольких строк с разными параметрами в командную строку.  Мне необходимо каждую строку этого вывода занести в отдельную переменную. Как это сделать - пока что не пойму. Прошу с этим помочь.

Comment: Покажите каким образом Вы вызываете программу из "оболочки" и передаёте ей параметры. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/206347/3129992

Comment: Process process = new Process();
      process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
      process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k " + str2 + str1;
      this.txtBoxFileName.Text = process.StartInfo.Arguments;
      process.Start();
   
   в str2 хранится имя приложения, запускаемого из командной строки, в str1 - переменные для этой программы

Comment: В вопрос добавьте код, а не в комментарий. Это поможет в будущем людям, которые столкнутся с похожей проблемой.

Answer (score 0):

Вы запускаете отдельный [процесс](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8) (основную программу), передавая ему аргументы или какие-то значения в `stdin`, а читаете его ответ из `stdout` этого процесса.

[Вот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/186833/1304136) того, как запускается компилятор:

```
Process compiler = new Process();
compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "csc.exe";
compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "/r:System.dll /out:sample.exe stdstr.cs";
compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
compiler.Start();    

Console.WriteLine(compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

compiler.WaitForExit();
```